# sql server json: Incrementing to a JSON array value or inserting if it doesn't exist

Tags: json, sql-server

```
-- Given an JSON value that looks like this
DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =N'{ "data" : [ { "id": 201903, "count": 1}, { "id": 201905, "count": 2} ] }'
SELECT @json
```

I want to either increment the value of a given key if it exists, or append to the array if the value doesn't exist

So for example, my key is `"201907"`.  If it exists, I will increment the value by 1, if it doesn't exist I will insert it at the end of the array.

Is my only choice here to load the entire array using `OPENJSON` and then querying to see if the key "201907" exists and increment if it does exist, and then writing it back out as JSON again?

Answer (score 0):

Two versions 
first when there is no datatable name(data) second is your case

OPENJSON requires Compatibility Level 130
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

```
DECLARE @_ID int = 201907

DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =N'{ "data" : [ { "id": 201903, "count": 1}, { "id": 201905, "count": 2} ] }'

SET @json =N'[{ "id": 201903, "count": 1}, { "id": 201905, "count": 2}   ]'
SELECT @json

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #TempTable

CREATE TABLE #TempTable(id  int, count int )

INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID,count)  
SELECT * FROM  
 OPENJSON ( @json )  
   WITH (        id   int '$.id'                
         ,   count int '$.count'  
   ) 

  select * from #TempTable


   update #TempTable set [count] = [count] + 1 where id = @_ID
   if(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
   begin
      print 'rowcount 0 = NO RECORD'
      insert into #TempTable (id,[count]) values (@_ID,1)
   end

   select * from #TempTable

    print 'back to JSON'

    SELECT id, [count]  
    FROM #TempTable  
    FOR JSON AUTO;
```

=================================
here with your JSON string

```
    DECLARE @_ID int = 201907

    DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @json =N'{ "data" : [ { "id": 201903, "count": 1}, { "id": 201905, 
     "count": 2} ] }'
    --SET @json =N'[{ "id": 201903, "count": 1}, { "id": 201905, "count": 2}   
     ]'
    SELECT @json

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #TempTable

    CREATE TABLE #TempTable(id  int, count int )

    INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID,count)  
    SELECT * FROM  
    OPENJSON ( @json, N'$.data' )  
       WITH (        id   int '$.id'                
         ,   count int '$.count'  
        ) 

    select * from #TempTable


     update #TempTable set [count] = [count] + 1 where id = @_ID
     if(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
     begin
     print 'rowcount 0 = NO RECORD'
     insert into #TempTable (id,[count]) values (@_ID,1)
     end

     select * from #TempTable

     print 'back to JSON'

     SELECT id, [count]  
     FROM #TempTable  
     FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

This is one possible solution, if you use SQL Server 2017+. With this version, you can pass an expression as argument in `JSON_MODIFY` and `JSON_VALUE` functions. What you need to do here is to get the index of the element in `data` JSON array with matching `id` value.

```
DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @key int

SET @json = N'{ "data" : [ { "id": 201903, "count": 1}, { "id": 201905, "count": 2} ] }'
SET @id = 201903

SET @key = COALESCE(
   (
   SELECT [key]
   FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.data')
   WHERE JSON_VALUE([value], '$.id') = @id
   ),
   -1
)

IF @key = -1 
   SELECT JSON_MODIFY(
      @json, 
      'append $.data', 
      JSON_QUERY(CONCAT(N'{"id": ', @id, N', "count": 1}'), '$')
   ) 
ELSE    
   SELECT JSON_MODIFY(
      @json, 
      CONCAT('$.data[', @key, '].count'), 
      JSON_VALUE(@json, CONCAT('$.data[', @key, '].count')) + 1
   )
```

**Solution 2:**

Your approach (*" .. to load the entire array using OPENJSON and then querying to see if the key exists and increment if it does exist, and then writing it back out as JSON again ..."*) is also an option and in this case you may try with the following statement:

```
DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @id int

SET @json = N'{ "data" : [ { "id": 201903, "count": 1}, { "id": 201905, "count": 2} ] }'
SET @id = 201907

--
SELECT id, SUM([count]) AS [count]
FROM (
   SELECT id, [count]
   FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.data')  WITH (
      id int '$.id',
      [count] int '$.count'
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT @id, 1
) t
GROUP BY id
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('data')
```